# MySQL statement replication - triggers causing duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have an ancient MySQL 5.0 master server that we're trying to migrate away from. Binary logs are enabled and statement replication is being used, going to a MariaDB 5.5 server directly. I have a legacy database with an audit table B. AFTER UPDATE ON TABLE A, INSERT INTO TABLE B (...values...). A copy of the entire row is added to table B. There are no primary keys on table B.

The behavior I'm seeing is that table B on slave has an order of magnitude more rows than table B does on master. It seems that 5+ duplicate rows get generated when a single update query occurs. Otherwise, all rows from master are accounted for on the slave and the data matches on those rows. This seems to be some sort of write amplification where a trigger is repeatedly firing on the same event.

Replicating across versions could be part of the problem.

Comment: The problem is that the slave server is running the triggers, which adds new rows to B, and is also receiving the replicas of the new rows from the master. So they get added multiple times.

Comment: I believe that in statement replication, rows added to table B on master are not replicated to the slave. Only the original SQL statement gets handed to the slave, and it independently fires the trigger. Even if they were replicated, I would expect a  predictable doubling of rows, not a random 5-9 (or more) duplicates.

Comment: Yeah, that is confusing. Hopefull when this gets migrated to [dba.se] someone there will be able to help you.